# Upgrading to Android API Level 33 fails to launch the main activity in the emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, android-13

I have an react-native app which I am trying to upgrade to use Android API level 33 as per the latest Android release requirements.

In my manifest, my app builds and runs if I have the following settings:

```
buildToolsVersion   = "33.0.0"
minSdkVersion       = 23
compileSdkVersion   = 33
targetSdkVersion    = 32
ndkVersion          = "23.1.7779620"
```

However, if I literally only change the `targetSdkVersion` to 33, my app builds successfully but fails to launch with the error:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.myapp.debug/com.myapp.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.myapp.debug/com.myapp.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

I can launch my app manually from within the emulator but I am wondering how to fix this launch issue. The activity name `com.myapp.debug/com.myapp.MainActivity` is correct. I can't see anything in particular in logcat.

*Note: I have tried cleaning the build, deleting the build directory, restarting the emulator / Android Studio, clearing the gradle cache, invalidating the caches within Android Studio, uninstalling the app via adb and the emulator but with no success. If I downgrade the `targetSdkVersion` back to 32 everything immediately works again.*

Any help / ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add ```AndroidManifest.xml```  file here

Comment: Same here. Any solution ?

Comment: Sorry - no luck here!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo, there is a fix related to target SDK 33 ([Fix deviceName exception on android sdk > 31](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/19666)). Check which version you are on or make this change in the expo-device package (with [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)):

Change it

```
"deviceName" to Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.contentResolver, "bluetooth_name")
```

To this

```
"deviceName" to run {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 31)
    Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.contentResolver, "bluetooth_name")
  else
    Settings.Global.getString(mContext.contentResolver, Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME)
},
```